# Javascript Drop down list

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
<script>

window.open("http://hostname:xxxxx/mdt/channelmonitorservlet","_parent");
document.getElementById("htmlb_2001_htmlb_1970_8").selectedIndex="2";
</script>
</body>
```

Hello, what is wrong with my code? I want it to open the page and then change the value of the dropdown list, but it doesn't, it only opens the page. I still new in javascript

Comment: `document.getElementById("htmlb_2001_htmlb_1970_8").selectedIndex="2";` has to be in newly opened window. In this script, this page, there is no element with this ID.

Comment: hi, can you please elaborate? :)

Comment: The question above does this, bear in mind the answer to the question (i.e. cross domain commands will not be allowed)

Comment: Check out the docs on [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document) and [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) for more info

Comment: Is the select list in the opened page or your current page? It's not clear.

Comment: Im not really going to another domain, I just want it to load the page, and then chage the dropdown list to a particular value. the dropdownlist "htmlb_2001_htmlb_1970_8" is on the page that the code is opening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `select` is on the page which is *opening* the window, the problem is probably that you're running the script before the DOM is ready, so it can't find the `select`. Try `console.log(document.getElementById("htmlb_2001_htmlb_1970_8"))` or `alert(document.getElementById("htmlb_2001_htmlb_1970_8"))` - if you see `null` then this is your problem.

If the select is on the page which is being *opened* (i.e. on hostname:xxxxx), you'll need the javascript to change the `select` to be on that page.

Comment: If the select is on the page which is being opened (i.e. on hostname:xxxxx), you'll need the javascript to change the select to be on that page. 

I think this is where I get the problem. the select is on the on hostname:xxxxx... I really need to read up on how to put it there.

Comment: @user120278 write same code in `document.ready` of the page being open

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
window.open("http://hostname:xxxxx/mdt/channelmonitorservlet","_parent");
document.getElementById("htmlb_2001_htmlb_1970_8").selectedIndex="2";
//alert("test");
});

</script>
</head> 

<body>

</body>

</html>

Comment: how can I reply a code here